# How to extract tar.gz including multi byte characters and prohibited characters on windows

Tags: java, c#, c++, windows, tar

I tried to extract the tar.gz using the following libraries, but none of them work perfectly.
The environment where I create tar.gz is linux, and the environment where I extract is windows.
And I cannot touch the linux server because the server is other company's.

M: Multi byte characters
W: Windows prohibited characters(: ;     / \（¥）| , * ?  " ＜  ＞)

SharpZiplib (C#)
  M: NG
  W: Can replace prohibited characters to other characters

```
                Stream st = new GZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(attFile));
                TarArchive archive = TarArchive.CreateInputTarArchive(st, TarBuffer.DefaultBlockFactor);
                archive.SetKeepOldFiles(false);
                archive.AsciiTranslate = false;
                archive.SetUserInfo(0, "", 0, "None");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Work);
                archive.ExtractContents(Work);
                archive.Close();
```

tar32.dll (C#)
  M: OK
  W: the data isn't generated

```
    public static void ExtractTarWithDLL(string Targzpath)
    {
        IntPtr i = new IntPtr();
        string szCmdLine = "-x " + Targzpath + " -o " + Path.GetDirectoryName(Targzpath);
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Targzpath));
        StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder(512);

        Tar(i, szCmdLine, error, 512);
    }
```

tar-cs (C#)
  M: NG
  W: Can replace prohibited characters to other characters

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Example of tar-cs library usage to extract tar.gz-archives.
    /// Please use the latest version (from trunk) of the library.
    /// </summary>
    public static class TarGZip
    {
        public static void Extract(string inputFile, string outputDirectory)
        {
            using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
            using (Stream tarStream = UnGZipSteam(inputStream))
            {
                var tarReader = new TarReader(tarStream);
                while (tarReader.MoveNext(false)) // Moves pointer to the next file in the tar archive.
                {
                    ExtractTarEntry(tarReader, outputDirectory);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Since GZipStream.Position Property is not implemented,
        /// it is necessary to use MemoryStream as intermediate storage.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputStream">The input stream.</param>
        /// <returns>Un-gzipped stream.</returns>
        private static Stream UnGZipSteam(Stream inputStream)
        {
            using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                gZipStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                return memoryStream;
            }
        }

        private static void ExtractTarEntry(TarReader tarReader, string outputDirectory)
        {
            string relativePath = tarReader.FileInfo.FileName;

            // Relative path can contain slash, not backslash.
            // Use Path.GetFullPath() method to convert path.
            //relativePath = relativePath.Replace('?','');
            string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(outputDirectory, relativePath));
            //string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(outputDirectory, "windows.txt"));

            switch (tarReader.FileInfo.EntryType)
            {
                case EntryType.File:
                case EntryType.FileObsolete:
                    using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create(fullPath))
                    {
                        // Read data from a current file to a Stream.
                        tarReader.Read(outputStream);
                    }
                    break;
                case EntryType.Directory:
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Not supported entry type: " + tarReader.FileInfo.EntryType);
            }
        }
    }
```

tarlib (C++)
  M: the data isn't generated
  W: the data isn't generated
I'm using this sample code. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/470999/tarlib-Windows-TAR-Library

ant.jar (java)
  M: By default, multi byte characters are replaced to '_'
  W: throws java.io.FileNotFoundException

```
public class Targz {

public void extract(Path path) throws IOException {


    if(!path.toString().endsWith(".tar.gz")){
        throw new Error("extension must be tar.gz.");
    }

    TarInputStream tin = new TarInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toFile())));

    for(TarEntry tarEnt = tin.getNextEntry(); tarEnt != null; tarEnt = tin.getNextEntry()) {
        if(tarEnt.isDirectory()){
            new File(tarEnt.getName()).mkdir();
        }
        else {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(tarEnt.getName()));
            tin.copyEntryContents(fos);
        }
    }
    tin.close();
}
```

}

Can anyone help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody explain why this should be off topic? The OP has already tried different frameworks/libraries with no success. So we can answer with yet another library or configurations to already tried ones solving the problem. This seems on topic to me.

Comment: there are so many things, which doesnt work with windows like symbolic links or to many subfolders. You do not have to use the linux server, only any linux system

Comment: Further to JaMaBing's comment, here are some ways to get a Linux system:  (A) Download a Linux Live CD and boot it on a computer without installing it. (B) Rent a Linux VPS by the hour on the net at Amazon EC2, Digitalocean, Nitrous.io or similar service.  Way less than $1/hour usually. (C) Use VirtualBox or VMWare to install a Linux virtual machine within Windows. In all cases, all you need to do is copy your .tar.gz file there, expand, go through it, get what you need. **change the bad names**,  zip it with zip or whatever for windows compatibility. Then delete the linux stuff when done.

Comment: **Towards getting this quesion reopened**: Could you post the commands or code snippets that you have tried?  Maybe something in there is incorrect... Click the *edit* link underneath your post.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to get a linux system to windows.
But it is difficult to adopt it because the environment is my customer's.
There are many restriction for changing the environment.

Comment: @ebyhr Please have a look on this gist https://gist.github.com/SubOptimal/acd3059a0fde04157b6b. The multibyte characters are not the problem. The reserved characters needs to be sanitized befor creating a directory/file.

Comment: @SubOptimal I confirmed that files can be extracted perfectly! Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

> tried to extract the tar.gz following libraries, but all of them isn't working perfectly. The environment where create tar.gz is linux, and the environment where extract it is windows. And I cannot touch the linux server because the server is other company's.

Hi, 
have you tried http://www.7-zip.org/ ?

Comment: Thank you for you rapid reply!
I tried 7-zip, but multi byte characters turn into garbage.